# How to give a name to a closure when implementing the method in iOS Swift (Syntax Question)

Tags: ios, swift, closures, completionhandler

I created these two methods below to log the user out.  When logout2(...) gets called, the user has the ability to make any changes in the anyFinalChanges before logout1() runs.

```
  private func logout1() {
    Cache.clearCache()
  }
  
  func logout2(anyFinalChanges: () -> (), userLoggedOut: () -> ()) {
    anyFinalChangesInThisClosure()
    logout()
    userLoggedOut()
  }
```

When I implement the logout method the second closure doesn't show the name

```
  .logOut2(anyFinalChanges: {

  }) { //No Name here.. why is that?

  }
```

How can I make it so the name of the closure will always appear?

Comment: It's the Swift's trailing closure syntax. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102 You can call your method like by specifying the name of the closure, it's just that Xcode (I guess you use Xcode) defaults to use this syntax.

Comment: Yeah I'm using xCode, but that clears things up, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is arguably a mistake in the Swift language. The rule is that if you use the trailing closure syntax (putting the anonymous function outside the parentheses of the method call), the first trailing closure gets no label. In your code there is just one trailing closure, so it's the first one, and it gets no label.

Chris Lattner, the original creator of Swift, has expressed regret about this choice, but at this point it's baked into the language and there's nothing one can do about it now.

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever a closure is the last parameter in a function swift by default omits the parameter label. However you can add it if you want like this:

```
logout2(anyFinalChanges: {
    
}, userLoggedOut: {
    
})
```

Comment: Oh very nice! In the end I am going to turn this into an SDK for others to implement so I guess it would be up to them to add it if they wanted to.